# Find word in text file

Tags: python, file, passwords, text-files, cpu-word

I tried to create a little password cracker just for myself.
The problem is that the program always tells me: `Password not found!`
I use a text file with just one word in a line!

```
pw = "password"

# The password in the list is "password"

pwlist = open('passwordlist.txt', 'r')
words = pwlist.readlines()
found = False

for password in words:
    if str(password) == pw:
        print(password)
        found = True
        break


if found == True:
   print("password found!")
else:
   print("Password not found!")
```

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? Do you know what each `password` actually contains? Also note you can just use `if found:`.

Comment: Your script works for me. Show content of `passwordlist.txt` and check for case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `readlines()` doesn't strip trailing carriage returns from the lines. Try

```
if password.strip() == pw:
```

Comment: That works! Thank you very much! I knew that it must have been an error like this one but I wasn't able to see that...

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like it should be working okay... can you confirm the word in the `.txt` file is indeed "password" (spelled the same way, no extra characters/blank spaces, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

The `readline()` method picks up the newline character at the end of each line `\n` (new line escape sequence).

You'll notice that if you open your text file it is actually two lines, the second line just has length `0`.

So to make this work, you'll need to replace:

```
words = pwlist.readlines()
```

With this:

```
words = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in pwlist]
```